# Show editable pdf as non-editable pdf in a browser using c#

Tags: c#, pdf, azure

I am getting editable pdf from azure blob. When I open it in new tab, it is in editable form. But I want to show it as non editable to user on link click in a browser. This is what I have done till now:

```
public ActionResult OpenPdf(string fileName)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureWebJobsStorageConnection"]);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer =
            blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertsBlobContainer"]);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        if (blob.Exists())
            blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        return File(stream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

How can i do this?

Comment: if you want to *show it as non-editable*, you have to *make it non-editable*, I assume you mean by *editable* that the PDF contains AcroForm or XFA form fields. To make it non-editable, you have to flatten the form. Flattening AcroForm forms should be a feature of any serious general-purpose PDF library. Flattening XFA forms is a less common feature.

Comment: How to convert this editable pdf to flat pdf?

Comment: *How to convert this editable pdf to flat pdf?* - You use a PDF library that supports form flattening. E.g. iText(Sharp) and friends e.g. allow form flattening. I don't know, though, whether they can be used in an Azure context.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'm trying the iTestSharp library. But the editable fields are not displaying correctly.

Comment: Please first check whether your form fields are AcroForm fields, XFA form fields, or a hybrid form. iText(Sharp) as is only knows how to flatten AcroForm fields. Furthermore you say *the editable fields are not displaying correctly*. What do you mean?

Comment: Instead of value it is showing black lines. How to check whether your form fields are AcroForm fields, XFA form fields, or a hybrid form.

Comment: *How to check ...* - inspect your PDF. Lookup the the trailer dictionary or the xref stream dictionary (depending on your document's cross references style); Follow the **Root** entry to the **Catalog** dictionary. From there follow the **AcroForm** entry to the *interactive form dictionary*. Check whether it contains a valid **XFA** entry. Or simply share the PDF for inspection.

Comment: How to get value from editable fields? e.g key is company and editable text against it is 'xxx'. But i'm getting 'Company' as key but not 'xxx' as value. So ican set this value against the key.

Comment: What kind of form do you have?

Comment: Got solution. I can get the value using form.GetListSelection(field.Key). Thank you mkl for your help :)

Comment: I'm having hybrid form.

Comment: If the form is in hybrid form and has been filled in in Adobe Reader (i.e. using the XFA structure), you'll need a special XFA flattener, e.g. [XFA worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xfa_worker) in case of the iText(Sharp) product family. I have not used it yet, though, and therefore can not help with details.

Comment: Ok. I'll Check that too. Currently I'm doing stamper.FormFlattening = true;
and working fine.

Comment: *Currently I'm doing stamper.FormFlattening = true; and working fine.* - didn't you say the fields were showing black lines then?

Comment: It was previously. But the issue has been resolved. I wanted to post answer here but i'm not able to. As I already mentioned got value using form.GetListSelection(field.Key).